# Node cache never expires and can't be cleared

Tags: 8, caching

BEFORE YOU ASK: I can't use Drush, this is a shared hosting, but I can use Composer.

In the constant struggle with Drupal 8.9 (8.9.11 to be exact) I've stumbled onto yet another issue: I have a simple node page with some company info and it remains cached forever. When I change and save it, I as an admin can see those changes. Anonymous users however still see the previous version.

And it's not just for a couple hours - it's been days.

I do not have any custom modules, nor cache-related contrib modules, in htaccess mod_expire settings are set to default.

I've tried many things - clearing cache in Performance panel, truncating cache tables in the database, completely disabling Internal Page Cache and Internal Dynamic Page Cache modules, saving the node again, running cron. Absolutely nothing helps. It seems impossible to clear the cache for anonymous users.

What else can I do? Are there any modules? Is it possible to write a script, maybe change some settings flag?

It's definitely related to URLs, as the moment I change that page's url, it can be viewed in it's updated state, but when I change it back, content reverts to it's cached state.

Comment: Is cron running regularly to purge the cache? Is a reverse proxy running?

Comment: Are you using CDN like Cloudflare? Maybe that's where the aggressive caching happens. Do you have a staging/dev/other version of the site with the old content? I think I once had an SSL certificate misconfiguration that read data from staging instead of production.

Comment: If nothing you've tried so far has worked, it is very likely to be a CDN like Cloudflare or another reverse-proxy cache like Varnish (as per the comments above). You could try a "cache busting string" when anonymous - if adding the string updates the page for anon, then it is almost certain to be another cache layer like Cloudflare or Varnish. Example: http://my-website.com?bustcache=1 Perhaps contact your shared hosting company & confirm this with them.